# Highchart hide default buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to hide default buttons ("Export" & "Print") in highchart export options.

you can have demo at http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/3496/   in this link there are 3 buttons
1. Custom Button
2. Export button
3. print Button.

In this case I want to show only  first button and hide "Export button" & "print Button"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can access each button preference with something like this:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        printButton: {
            symbol: 'circle'
        },
        exportButton: {
            enabled: false
        }    
    }
}
```

an expandable example with your custom button would be:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        printButton: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exportButton: {
            enabled: false
        },
        custom: {
            symbol: 'diamond',
            x: -62,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
            _titleKey: 'printButtonTitle',
            onclick: function () {
                alert('click!')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to highcharts. It looks like the individual button disable is not working in the latest version?

Comment: Yes, in new version, it still shows the buttons. its not hiding. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

For anyone else who is using a newer version of highcharts and the selected answer doesn't work, you need to use the below instead to hide the button.

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                enabled: false
            }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible as an option, but you can hide the default buttons then create your own using html. Then you can bind your custom button as you need.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });

console.log( Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols )​
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to hide default custom buttons,you could simply use:

```
exporting: {
      buttons: {
        contextButton: {
          enabled: false
        },
        printButton: {
            enabled: false,
        },
      }
    }
```

If you want to use your own custom button or label you can use this:

```
exporting: {
      buttons: {
        contextButton: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exportButton: {
            text: `Chrome`,
            _titleKey: "yourKey",
            onclick:function(){
            alert('clicked Chrome');
            },
            x:-410
        },

        printButton: {
            enabled: false,
            text: `IE: `,
             _titleKey:"myKey",
            onclick: function () {
                alert('clicked IE');
            },
            x:-400,
            y:30
        },          
      }
    },
```

in this i have disabled default as well as printButton, you can use x and y to set the positions of the label.
You can find my code in fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/m3yegczx/20/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework then you can hide by this way.

```
    HIOptions *options = [[HIOptions alloc]init];
    HIExporting *exporting = [[HIExporting alloc]init];
    exporting.enabled = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:false];
    options.exporting = exporting;
```

Answer (score 0):

As for current highcharts (7.2.1), you can hide them by setting option below

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: ["downloadPNG", "downloadJPEG", "downloadPDF", "downloadSVG"]
        }
    }
}
```

Check API at https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems