# highcharts: disable default buttons but keep custom button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2d2hrnzw/), I've tried to disable the default highcharts button while keeping the custom button, but I'm unable to actually do so. To disable the default buttons but keep the custom button, I tried this:

```
exporting: {
            buttons: {
                printButton: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exportButton: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                customButton: {
                    x: -62,
                    onclick: function () {
                        alert('Clicked');
                    },
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }
        }
```

All the other SO questions I've seen, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375871/highchart-hide-default-buttons) one, have suggested this method for disabling the default buttons, and I'm not quite sure why this isn't working. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out the answer was to set `contextButton: false`.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            enabled: false
        },
        customButton: {
            x: -62,
            onclick: function () {
                alert('Clicked');
            },
            symbol: 'circle'
        }
    }
}
```

see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a2331rue/).